# Is it possible to reproduce the Mac IME switching model?

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus, japanese

On Macs, you can set up your language keyboard to toggle between various Japanese input methods and keyboards in the same "set":

[image]

In my case, with this, I can hit the "switch keyboard layout" section and toggle between a US, French, then "US/Hiragana IME"/"US/Katanana IME", etc.

When I just set up the (I believe) `ibus-mozc` IME for Ubuntu in Gnome, when typing in Japanese I have to first switch to the "Japanese (Mozc)" layout, *then* use some Mozc-only key command to switch input methods.

Is there a way to instead make the IME methods first class? I am fine switching IME setups entirely, but this is a constant source of frustration for me given the keyboard layouts I use.

Comment: As someone who uses both English and Japanese constantly for work, this is something that I’ve not found a solution for. I generally get around the “frustration” by rebooting once a month, as the Mocz config will remember my  input preference after its first entered 

Comment: I do not understand why Katakana Japanese is so important for you. Japanese people convert Katakana from Hiragana as same as we do it to Kanji words.

Comment: Despite my best efforts when trying to type in my name into a web form when the IME is in hiragana mode it tends to offer hiragana. Similar issues with when I need to type full-width. I get there are shortcuts for conversion, though, and if I had hiragana working that would be the best

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to avoid this two times settings to get Hiragana input when we switch to Japanese mode.

1. Use `fcitx-mozc`
2. Write a script to switch Japanese Mozc and select Hiragana by `xdotool`
3. Fix `ibus-mozc` type Hiragana when we switch it

#1 and #3 answers are found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717098/make-ibus-mozc-start-in-hiragana-rather-than-direct-input-mode)

NOTE: #3 method, the compile failed on 22.04 LTS

```
dpkg-buildpackage error debian/rules clean subprocess returned exit status 2
```